# Windows Xp Boot time tool

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any tool which can show me the causes of a slow Windows Xp boot and shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to check what is starting with the bootup -- use [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) .
It would also help track what is running (and needs to be shutdown at the end) -- [procexp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
Another reference: [How to fix Windows XP Slow Startup And Shutdown Problems](http://www.articlesbase.com/operating-systems-articles/how-to-fix-windows-xp-slow-startup-and-shutdown-problems-1281444.html).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is [Bootviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BootVis), It is no longer supported by Microsoft and the download link comes from a third party, so I have [linked to the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BootVis) about it and you can make up your own mind if you want to use it.